# Sum columns based off conditionals - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to sum specific columns in a df where a condition is met. Where `Group` == `Group_A`, I want to sum `A_4','B_4`. However, where `Group` == `Group_B`, I want to pass the sum of `A_1','B_1` to the same column. I need to pass the function at the same time otherwise I end up with nan values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({         
    'Group_A' : ['Red','Red','Red','Red','Red',],   
    'Group_B' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue',],                              
    'Group' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Red','Blue',],   
    'A_1' : [7,6,8,0,4],                                   
    'B_1' : [6,7,11,1,4],  
    'A_4' : [1,1,1,6,4],                                   
    'B_4' : [3,3,3,9,5],                                                           
    })

df['Sum'] = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_A'],['A_4','B_4']].sum(axis=1)
df['Sum'] = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_B'],['A_1','B_1']].sum(axis=1)
```

intended output:

```
  Group_A Group_B Group  A_1  B_1  A_4  B_4   Sum
0     Red    Blue  Blue    7    6    1    3  13.0
1     Red    Blue  Blue    6    7    1    3  13.0
2     Red    Blue  Blue    8   11    1    3  19.0
3     Red    Blue   Red    0    1    6    9  15.0
4     Red    Blue  Blue    4    4    4    5   8.0
```

Update:

Could subtraction replace the sum method without drawing an error?

```
sub1 = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_A'], df['A_4'].sub(df['B_4'])]
sub2 = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_B'], df['A_1'].sub(df['B_1'])]

df['Sub'] = Sum1.append(Sum2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, save the sum to series, and then update the dataframe:

```
Sum1 = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_A'],['A_4','B_4']].sum(axis=1)
Sum2 = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_B'],['A_1','B_1']].sum(axis=1)
df['Sum']=Sum1.append(Sum2)
```

as mentioned in comments, if you want to subtract, let's say Bs from As, then you can do something like this:

```
Sum1 = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_A'],['A_4','B_4']].apply(lambda x: x['A_4'] - x['B_4'],axis=1)
Sum2 = df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group_B'],['A_1','B_1']].apply(lambda x: x['A_1'] - x['B_1'],axis=1)
df['Sum']=Sum1.append(Sum2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to include a subtraction instead of sum?

Comment: @Chopin, you're welcome, I've updated the answer to include subtraction too

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.select` here which is usually much faster:

```
import numpy as np

condlist = [
    df.Group.eq(df.Group_A),
    df.Group.eq(df.Group_B)
]

choicelist = [
    df.filter(like='_4').sum(1),
    df.filter(like='_1').sum(1)
]

df['sum'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

NOTE: Replace filter with required columns if required. And if you've simple else-if condition `np.where` will also work.

Answer (score -1):

np.where() is tailor made for such scenarios

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({         
    'Group_A' : ['Red','Red','Red','Red','Red',],   
    'Group_B' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue',],                              
    'Group' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Red','Blue',],   
    'A_1' : [7,6,8,0,4],                                   
    'B_1' : [6,7,11,1,4],  
    'A_4' : [1,1,1,6,4],                                   
    'B_4' : [3,3,3,9,5],                                                           
    })

df['Sum'] = np.where(df["Group"]==df["Group_A"],df["A_4"]+df["B_4"], df["A_1"]+df["B_1"])
```

Comment: This will fail in some scenarios. You're only checking the 1st condition and then you're setting one default option if that particular condition is false. Meaning if the group doesn't equal to groupA or groupB in that case also it will sum A_1 and B_1

Comment: Yes, but Depends on the scenario. If the use case is simplistic, no need to unnecessarily create complicated solutions.

Comment: Yeh, my intended output was right the first time. I need to pass two separate conditions.